# Does the blower fan move when the AC window unit is set to fan mode?

Tags: hvac

I wonder if the blower fan works or spins when the AC unit is set to fan mode (no cooling). I do not know much about AC units, though from what I read AC window units contain two fans which are the blower fan behind the evaporator coil and the one to the far back. I want to know if both fan spin on fan mode. If only the fan to the far back is the one that spins, then I would like to know if the blower fan can move as a side effect of the back fan spinning.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A window A/C in Fan mode may run both the inside and outside fans together.
They are often spun by the same motor so even in fan mode the outside fan will spin, and do nothing useful while the inside one just circulates air in the house or, with some A/Cs, brings in outside air.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I want to confirm something. By inside fan do you mean the blower fan which is behind the evaporator coil?

Comment: I tried switching from cooling mode to fan mode and I could hear the fan behind the evaporator coil slowing down. I am not sure if it stops or not. My AC unit is Carrier from 20+ years ago.

Comment: Yes, the "inside" fan is the one that circulates room air through the evaporator.  That is the "Fan" for Fan Mode.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information. I am a bit boggled on why I hear a powering down fan sound as soon as I switch from cooling mode into fan mode. Does the inside fan spin at a lower speed on fan mode than it is on cooling mode?

Comment: Maybe you are hearing the compressor wind down.